# Synergy Multi Monitor Client/Server Config Mouse shift Issue

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, synergy, kvm-switch

I am trying to achieve the best synergy mouse "shift" from server to client and vice versa but having some trouble due to either synergy's limitation or Windows display configuration (server & client are both win10), but I can't figure out which one.To best describe my setup, I have created a simple diagram below.

[image: monitor-cable & screen config]

Client
Now when I move my mouse from my laptop to VGA connected "screen 2" the top edge is used - Perfect

Server
When I move my mouse from my PC DVI "screen 2" to the HDMI "screen 1" the top edge is used - Perfect

Now my issue is moving from server to client and vice versa. I want to be able to move directly across the left edge from Server "screen 2" to Client "screen 2" OR bottom edge of server "screen 2" to Client laptop "screen 1". However, I cannot get the correct config set up in windows or synergy to do this.

Synergy Config

[image]

The best I could do was move the mouse up from "screen 2" to "screen 1" in the server and then shift to the left edge to get to my client "screen 2". This is not the best way because my screen 2 will not be on at all times (its a wall-mounted TV). What is the best configuration to make it so the left or bottom edge of server "screen 2" is used to move to the client?

I think the issue might be that my AMD graphics card is prioritizing the HDMI display as 1 and DVI as 2 even though I set the DVI display as the "main display" in windows configuration. How can I fix this with out switching out the inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm still trying to get synergy to recognize my client's second monitor..

Answer (score 1):

I've recently set up something similar to this using Synergy.
Unfortunately Synergy only lets you transition off screen edges that are on the edge of each machine's "Virtual Display" (the rectangle that encompasses the pixels for all of your screens).  Synergy does however let you add transitions from a machine to itself which gives us some sort of workaround.

I first moved my lower screen (`server_2`) above my upper screen (`server_1`) in the Windows settings: [Physical location vs Location in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9cX9.png).  This allows us to have all the edges we want to transition over on the edge of the Virtual Display.
Then I wrote a Synergy config file to wrap my mouse around from the top of `server_2` to the bottom of `server_1` by using the percentages:

```
section: links
    server:
        up(0,55) = server(45,100)
        down(45,100) = server(0,55)
end
```

Next I added in the configuration to go to the client monitor:

```
section: links
    server:
        up(0,55) = server(45,100)
        down(45,100) = server(0,55)
        left(0,40) = client(0,100)
        down(0,45) = client(0,100)
    client:
        right(0,100) = server(0,40)
        up(0,100) = client(0,45)
end
```

Advantages:

- Allows movement from client to server in all the expected places
- Doesn't require moving any display inputs
- Doesn't require any extra software (I looked at some other solutions which added a dummy screen)

Disadvantages:

- There is a portal from the bottom of `server_2` to the top of `server_1` (which is Windows original screen transition)
- To drag things from `server_1` to `server_2` you need to go in an unexpected direction
- You can't place windows that span both `server_1` and `server_2` how you'd expect